# XDocument.Descendants() filters too much

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an XML string that I am trying to select elements from and I find I am confused about the XDocument.Decendents() method. Here is sample XML.

```
 <response>
  <control>
    <status>success</status>
    <dtdversion>3.0</dtdversion>
  </control>
  <operation>
    <authentication>
      <status>success</status>
      <userid>jsmith</userid>
      <companyid>1621876182</companyid>
      <sessiontimestamp>2017-10-23T11:57:27-07:00</sessiontimestamp>
    </authentication>
    <result>
      <status>success</status>
      <function>GetFields</function>
      <controlid>723973</controlid>
      <data listtype="All" count="1">
        <type fieldname="ID">User Id</type>
        <type fieldname="FIRSTNAME">User First Name</type>
        <type fieldname="LASTNAME">User Last Name</type>
        <type fieldname="MIDDLEINITIAL">User Middle Initial</type>
        <type fieldname="ADDRESS1">User Address 1</type>
        <type fieldname="ADDRESS2">User Address 1</type>
        <type fieldname="CITY">City of User Residence</type>
        <type fieldname="STATE">State of User Residence</type>
        <type fieldname="PHONENUMBER">User Phone Number</type>
        <type fieldname="EMAIL">User Email Address</type>
      </data>
    </result>
  </operation>
</response>
```

My goal is to obtain a list of the node values within the `data` node. I find that the following works and returns a list of 10 elements.

```
List<string> nodeList = xml.Descendants().Attributes("fieldname").Select(x => x.Value).ToList<string>();
```

What confuses me is that I tried to specify the `data` node as the only node I should look under for the child nodes. I just added **"data"** as an `XName` parameter to the `Descendants()` method.

```
List<string> nodeList = xml.Descendants("data").Attributes("fieldname").Select(x => x.Value).ToList<string>();
```

The result in this case returned a `nodeList` count of zero. I was just seeking to me more specific in defining which nodes should be selected so that no other nodes in the XML document with an attribute name of "fieldname" would be selected other than those that were child elements of the `<data>` node. I am not sure why I get zero results and was hoping someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: How many entries do you expect?

Comment: I am expecting 10 nodes back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think descendants filters the descendants which are of type data, but there are no data-descendants with an attribute.
Try this:

```
List<string> nodeList = xml.Descendants("data").Descendants().Attributes("fieldname").Select(x => x.Value).ToList<string>();
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the explanation. So it looks like `Descendants("data")` must just select the descendents of the root node that have the value of `data`. The second `Descendants()` must be needed to select the child nodes.